# Check Power of a value in DB2

Tags: db2

In DB2, i want to do 10 to the power of 99.

I tried POWER(10,99)

But Error I get:
SQL Error [22003]: Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception occurred.. SQLCODE=-802, SQLSTATE=22003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the following depending on the output data type you prefer.

```
POWER(decfloat(10), 99)
POWER(double(10), 99)
```